# Android Studio панели не становятся обратно белыми

Tags: android-studio

Изначально все было в светлой теме, затем перешел на темную и все стало темным - и панели и редактор. Сейчас захотел вернуться обратно на светлую, но меняет цвет только редактор.

Как сделать все обратно светлым?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как тему меняешь?

Comment: @Alex78191, Ctrl+Alt+S>Editor>Colors&Fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменяй тему в `File -> Settings -> Appearance`

Comment: Да, я как раз умудрился найти вопрос на enSO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986996/how-to-revert-theme-from-darcula-to-default-in-android-studio Спасибо!